# Sutta pitaka in plain English

Tags: reference-request, sutras

Where can I find sutta pitaka translations in plain English preferably from an author that has practised meditation. If the English is relevant to today's problems and sufferings, even better. Word to word translations are a bit boring to read and understand.

I am hoping to gain inspiration for my practice by reading and memorising short suttas. I really like pariyatti publications but there only a handful I could find.

Maybe someone knows if I can read the entire sutta pitaka online along with sub commentaries. That would help.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for not doing research. The mods can close this question if they wish.